# how to make pandas dataframe with nested dictionaries after exploded arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a two data frames as follow.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Create data set.
dataSet1 = {'id': ['A', 'A', 'A','A','B','B','B','C'],
           'id_2': [1, 2, 3, 3, 1,2,3,1],
           'id_3' : [9,13,12,11,9,20,22,13]}
dataSet2 = {'id_2': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4],
           'serial_number' : [10,11,12,13,15,11,12,13,20,15,10,15]}
# Create dataframe with data set and named columns.
df_map1 = pd.DataFrame(dataSet1, columns= ['id', 'id_2', 'id_3'])

df_map2 = pd.DataFrame(dataSet2, columns= ['id_2', 'serial_number'])

df_map1

   id id_2 id_3
0   A   1   9
1   A   2   13
2   A   3   12
3   A   3   11
4   B   1   9
5   B   2   20
6   B   3   22
7   C   1   13

  id_2  serial_number
0   1   10
1   1   11
2   1   12
3   1   13
4   1   15
5   2   11
6   2   12
7   2   13
8   3   20
9   3   15
10  4   10
11  4   15
```

such that id follow by id_2 and id_3.

I created dictionary for mapping for df_map1 so we know what's going on and same for df_map2.

```
mapping_dict = {}
for lst in df_map1.values:
    
    leaf = mapping_dict
    for path in lst[:-2]:
        
        leaf = leaf.setdefault(path, {})
    leaf.setdefault(lst[-2], list()).append(lst[-1])

{'A': {1: [9], 2: [13], 3: [12, 11]},
 'B': {1: [9], 2: [20], 3: [22]},
 'C': {1: [13]}}

df_map2 = df_map2[df_map2['id_2'].isin(df_map1['id_2'].unique().tolist())]

{1: [10, 11, 12, 13, 15], 2: [11, 12, 13], 3: [20, 15]}
```

now we defined our 2 mappings out of df_map1 and df_map2
what i want to do is, based on these dictionaries,

ie)

```
{'A' : {1: [9] } <--- from map1

{1: [10, 11, 12, 13, 15]} <--- from map2
```

such that it becomes '9' : [10,11,12,13,15],
and create array that creates random number from **0 to 2** for 4 or n number of columns of arrays that looks like the following.

DESIRED ARRAY : ( basically exploding, and each column represent as **sequence** that restarts for each combination)

```
1st row : 9 | 10 [ 2, 1, 2, 1]
2nd row : 9 | 11 [ 0, 1, 0, 2]
3rd row : 9 | 12 [ 0, 0, 0, 1]
4th row : 9 | 13 [ 0, 2, 2, 2]
5th row : 9 | 15 [ 0, 1, 1, 2]
```

and turns this back to pandas Dataframe which will look like this

```
   id_3 serial_number   value    sequence
0   9      10            2          1
1   9      10            1          2
2   9      10            2          3
3   9      10            1          4
4   9      11            0          1
5   9      11            1          2
6   9      11            0          3
7   9      11            2          4
```

this is just an example of regards to this mapping

```
{'A' : {1: [9] } <--- from map1

{1: [10, 11, 12, 13, 15]} <--- from map2
```

if we have this case :

```
3: [12, 11]   <--- from map1
3: [20, 15]   <--- from map2

it will become
{'12' : [20,15], '11' : [20,15] }
```

Comment: what is exactly the question?

Comment: using these map1 and map2 dictionaries or it does not need to be dictionaries if we know straight answer using pandas. but in the end we would like to create desired dataframe that looks like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can skip the intermediate dictionaries and use `merge`for your mapping steps.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2)

rand_num_min = 0
rand_num_max = 2
rand_num_len = 4
```

Here comes the `merge`

```
step1 = df_map1.merge(df_map2, on='id_2', how='left')
```

Then we generate a list of 4 random numbers for each row,

```
step1['value'] = list(np.random.randint(rand_num_min, rand_num_max+1, (len(step1), rand_num_len)))
```

and explode each list to multiple rows

```
step2 = step1.explode('value')
```

Exploded rows share the same `index` from before they are exploded, so we can use that with `groupby` and `cumcount` to assign the `sequence`

```
step2['sequence'] = step2.groupby(step2.index).cumcount()+1
```

Lastly, take care the formatting.

```
step2.reset_index(drop=True).drop(columns=['id', 'id_2'])
```